# Can we use another route within a route in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

So I have index.js, userRoute, and friendRoute

in index.js

```
const app = express()
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user')
app.use('/users', userRoutes)
```

in /routes/user.js, I want to append /friends routes

```
const friendRoutes = require('../routes/friend')
router.use('/:username/friends', friendRoutes)
```

The expected result that I want is get the user's list of friends
`/users/:username/friends`

But I didn't get the username params when I tried to hit the url
Is there any way to achieve the expected result?
or is there best practice of doing this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your /routes/user.js

```
const friendRoutes = require('../routes/friend')
router.use('/:username/friends', (req, res, next) => {
    req.username = req.params.username;
    next();
}, friendRoutes);
```

Use req.username in your /routes/friend.js to get the params value

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.friendRoutes = async (req, res)=>{
    const username = req.params.username;
    console.log(username)
}

// or

exports.friendRoutes = async (req, res)=>{
    const {username} = req.params;
    console.log(username)
}
```